# c# perform a SUM while convert.todouble is null

Tags: c#

I'm a `C#` novice and I would like to perform following sum instead one or both Text Value return `null` value.

```
alfa = Convert.ToDouble(beta.Text.Replace("°", "")) + Convert.ToDouble(gamma.Text.Replace("°", ""));
```

That text objects are empty or they includes with a number and ° symbol like this `37,88°`. I would avoid to do something like following because this is not what I would like to do:

```
double betaText;
double gammaText;

if (beta.Text != "")
{
    betaText = Convert.ToDouble(beta.Text.Replace("°", ""));
}
if (gamma.Text != "")
{
    gammaText = Convert.ToDouble(gamma.Text.Replace("°", ""))
}
alfa = betaText + gammaText;
```

And I would also to avoid to do something like this because I simply want to do a Sum as I've done on the top in a single line only.

How can I do?

```
if (double.TryParse(beta.Text.Replace("°", ""), out betaText))
{
}
if (double.TryParse(gamma.Text.Replace("°", ""), out gammaText))
{
}
alfa = betaText + gammaText;
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions
Cheers

Comment: are 'beta' and 'gamma' textboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator I suppose:

```
double sum =
    (beta.Text == string.Empty ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(beta.Text.Replace("°", ""))) +   
    (gamma.Text == string.Empty ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(gamma.Text.Replace("°", "")));
```

This treat empty strings as 0s.

This can be collapsed to one line, as you wished.

However, I think you are sacrificing readability by reducing this whole thing to one line.

I suggest you extracting this complicated logic into a method and just call that method instead:

```
int sum = SumOfDegreesString(beta.Text, gamma.Text);

private static double SumOfDegreesString(string s1, string s2) {
    double a = 0, b = 0;
    double.TryParse(s1.Replace("°", ""), out a);
    double.TryParse(s2.Replace("°", ""), out b);
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: @orecchionebruno If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: I forgot to say that if a value is empty, it must be assigned as "0" because I must do the Sum in any case

Comment: @orecchionebruno So if only one value is empty, you want the sum to be the other value?

Comment: so I should use OR instead AND operator